# make fields non-serialized by default in c#

Tags: c#, .net, class, serialization, field

Is it possible to make fields non-serialized by default in c#, something that works in .NET 2.0 as well?

Most of the fields in the Serialized class are non-serialized and only few fields require serialization.

I know that one attribute can be applied to multiple fields, but this is not what I need.

The class is serialized into XML.

```
[Serializable()]
class MyClass
{
  [NonSerialized]
  protected double field1;
}
```

Comment: What kind of serialization?

Comment: @RonBeyer, default in .NET.

Comment: @denfromufa WCF? XML? JSON?  Could you post an example of how your are currently serializing this type in code?

Comment: .NET has many ways of serialization. Show your code.

Comment: @Mike, CodeCaster, the code is posted above

Comment: The serialization code...

Comment: @denfromufa That is not the code we are asking for.  That is merely the class definition.  Please show us the code you are using to serialize the type into some format.

Comment: it is serialized into XML

Comment: why does it matter? XML, JSON, etc.?

Comment: Because each serializer has its own conventions.

Comment: and because most serializers will ignore protected members anyway. They serialize the public interface only.

Comment: @Ralf, apparently the XML serializer that we use does not ignore protected, private, and internal members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on exactly how you are serializing your types, you can use a `DataContract` attribute on your class.  This allows you to decorate the properties that you want to serialize using the `DataMember` attribute.

When combined with the `DataContractSerializer`, serialization takes uses an opt-in approach, and Properties missing the attribute will not be serialized.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract]
class MyClass
{      
    [DataMember]
    protected double field1; // This field is serialized

    protected double secretField; // This field is not        
}
```

Comment: is this possible for fields? You only mentioned properties.

Comment: The `DataMember` attribute is legal on fields, however the typical convention is to favor using properties over fields (even beyond serializiation).

Comment: can you give simple example with `DataContract` used for my purpose?

Comment: I've added an example class declaration using the `DataContract` attributes.

Comment: where does `DataContractSerializer` goes?

Comment: DataContractSerializer does not work in .NET 2.0, which I have to support

Comment: A relevant detail that should be included in your question.